# Proof of work for standard computers

Tags: proof-of-work

I'm interested in a proof-of-work system that works well on standard computers without using the GPU.

Properties the system should have:

1. **Seed based proof-of-work.**
   There is no distinguished challenger who can solve the problem efficiently. A typical seed is a 256 bit hash of a public key.
2. **Minimize the advantage an attacker gains from specialized hardware.**
   The legitimate worker has a standard desktop or notebook. He's willing to commit about 1GB of memory and his CPU to calculate the proof. The time he spends is a few minutes to a few hours, depending what grade the proof should have.
   The attacker can use specialized hardware including GPU, FPGA and ASIC. The amount of money he spends for hardware and electricity to calculate the proof should be maximal.
3. **Efficient verification**
   Verifying the proof should be cheap. For example taking 1ms and 1MB of memory.
4. **Small proof**
   A 16 byte proof would be ideal, but a few kilobytes would be OK too.
5. **Predictable duration**
   For many proof systems each attempt is independent, making it hard to predict when you succeed. Success peaking around the average time would be nice. This is just a nice-to-have feature, and I'd be content with a system that only satisfies 1 to 4.

Systems I know, but that don't satisfy my requirements:

1. Hash prefixes for standard hash functions such as SHA-2. This fulfills 1, 3 and 4, but utterly fails 2. Specialized hardware is *much* more efficient than the target hardware.
2. Hash prefixes for scrypt. This fulfills 1, 2 and 4. But it fails 3, because verification requires just as much memory as working, and verification time is a bit long too.

I believe it is possible to create a system that fulfills the four main requirements. My idea is solving a problem which in principle can be solved with little memory, but the chance of success is small, and thus the amount of work is very large, in that case. But if you are willing to commit significant amounts of RAM, you can run a different algorithm, that solves the problem efficiently.

Comment: Thinking out loud, have you checked this work? people.cs.pitt.edu/~mehmud/docs/abliz09tourpuzzle.pdf‎

Comment: Two candidates come to mind.  (1) Find an input to scrypt that makes the first 20 bits of its output all zeros.  Verification is now pretty cheap.  (2) Use timelock puzzles.  They admit a very large ratio between the time to solve the puzzle vs the time to construct the puzzle (or to verify the solution).

Comment: @D.W. 1) Scrypt with sufficient memory (say 1GB) use isn't cheap to verify. Scrypt is pretty much the baseline against which to compare a better scheme. 2) The only time lock puzzles I know are sequential, but don't need much memory. So you can solve many instances in parallel with many cheap cores.

Comment: [Equihash](https://www.internetsociety.org/sites/default/files/blogs-media/equihash-asymmetric-proof-of-work-based-generalized-birthday-problem.pdf) might fit the requirements.

Answer (score 5):

$\quad$ chosen-prefix partial *collisions* for scrypt

This does somewhat better at #3 than your second option because

working requires storing previously obtained scrypt outputs.

(I think it would be better to require a at most a given Hamming distance between the outputs rather

than equality of a specific set of bits of the output. $\:$ The first of those would require storing the

entirety of the outputs, while the second would only require storing the relevant bits of the output.)

Comment: *Great* answer.

Comment: At least exact collisions do not solve the problem of requiring more memory on the work side than on the verifier side; finding exact collisions can be done with little memory, see [_Parallel Collision Search with Cryptanalytic Applications_](http://people.scs.carleton.ca/~paulv/papers/JoC97.pdf). I do not know what happens for partial collisions, but I suspect there are shortcuts.

Comment: I already considered this idea. The main issue with this idea is that you store the output in shared memory, allowing an attacker to use a high number of workers on that memory. So it still fails 3.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Huh. It passes 3. To verify, you just compute the two hashes and see how close they are. You don't have to use hash operations that require lots of memory, so verification can be cheap.

Comment: @fgrieu: That's why he suggested Hamming distance. Matching specific bits reduces the memory needed. And exact matches make it too easy to use cryptographic shortcuts. You could also use the hash of the two hashes concatenated (if that's less than the proof of work target, then the PoW is accepted).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I like your idea of a second-level scrypt as the collision-ranking criteria: it gives confidence that no shortcut exists to either storing the first-level scrypt hashes among which partial collisions are thought, or recomputing them at high cost to conserve on that memory. Two issues remain: a) scrypt must use little memory (because of #3), and may thus become a good target for GPU; b) most of the memory required to store the first-level scrypt hashes can be slow and cheap as in rotating disk (split these in n*n blocks, and you need only 2*n blocks in fast memory).

Comment: @fgrieu: With that method, even if you use a variant of `scrypt` that doesn't use much memory, you still need a lot of memory to store the first-round results, and that is not needed for verification. You can, in fact, tune this by how much harder the first-round hash is than the second. The harder the first-round hash is relative to the second, the more important it is to store previous results.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Yes. Again I appreciate your strengthening of the original answer. I'm only pointing that most of the required memory can be slow, and a GPU may give an advantage to the worker.

Comment: For prefix collisions it's properties are much worse than a prefix pre-image with the same hash function(scrypt or plain hash). An attacker who as large shared memory and many small parallel If you want to use high memory requirement to give an advantage to a CPU, the worker must not be able to share that memory between cores. That's because a PC has a lot of memory per core, but the total amount of memory isn't larger than that of the attacker.

Comment: For hamming distance, I don't know what data structure the worker should use to efficiently check if a near-collision occurred. If you think hamming distance works well, please post an answer describing how it would work in practice @DavidSchwartz.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: The worse it works, the better. The idea is to make it hard.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz You need to make it work well on standard computers, and hard on specialized computers. And at least for hamming-distance I don't see what kind of algorithm you envision.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: It just needs to be about equally hard on both. Algorithms would be memory-limited, and specialized computers don't have a significant memory advantage over general-purpose computers like they do with calculations not involving tests or branches (like SHA256).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The please post an answer that describes an algorithm. I for one see no way to make collisions of any kind work. My impression is that a computer with 1GB memory and a billion cores would solve your problem a billion times as fast as a computer with a single core, since there are n^2 possible pairings he can pick from to compare.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: If a computer with a billion cores solved it a billion times faster, that would give no advantage for the specialized hardware. You could just as well use a billion regular cores. (For algorithms like SHA256, a specialized computer with 200 cores can be millions of times faster than a general purpose computer with 4 cores.)

Answer (score 2):

I designed Cuckoo Cycle at https://github.com/tromp/cuckoo as the first trivially verifiable, scalable and time-memory-trade-off-hard proof-of-work system. It parallellizes reasonably well up to at least 12 CPU-threads, but is expected to saturate the memory due to random access latencies for some small multiple of that. A GPU has memory with tons of bandwidth but much worse random access latencies, so may not be able to compete.
See the whitepaper for details.